# How to make Ubuntu Software Center work with custom repository?

Tags: software-center

I am making a custom Ubuntu distribution with custom repository but how to add My repositories to it and can others also upload their packages to my repository

Answer (score 1):

In the chroot environment add your repo to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`. See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#edit) on how to format a sources.list entry.

Alternatively, add the repo with the command `add-apt-repository`.

Afterwards run `apt-get update` to load the repository information into APT's cache.